# Why is the element not disappearing when mouse leaves area?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I move the cursor inside of the media-slider-wrap the slider-paging follows the cursor, which is what I want. But when the mouse leaves the media-slider-wrap the slider-paging should disappear straight away, instead it keeps following the mouse.. If you move the cursor really slow out of the div then the slider-paging will basically show forever unless you move the cursor fast...

Any idea how to fix this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/abwVXGY) for reference

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slider").each(function () {
      _this = $(this);

      _this.mousemove(function(e){
          var offset = _this.offset();
          var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();

          var x = (e.clientX - rect.left);
          var y = (e.clientY - rect.top);

          $(this).find('.slider-paging').show();
          $(this).find('.slider-paging').css("top", y).css("left", x);

      });
      _this.mouseleave(function(e){
          $(this).find('.slider-paging').hide();
      });

  });
});
```

```css
.media-slider-wrap {
  width: fit-content;
}
.slider-paging {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display:none;
}
.slider-image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="media-slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider">
     <div class="slider-image"></div>
     <div class="slider-paging">1/4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You want `.slider-paging` disappear on mouse leave the red area?

Comment: Yeah. If you leave the area at the moment it disappears f you move the mouse quick, but if you move it out slow it stays...

Comment: You bind `mouseleave` on `.media-slider-wrap` which is larger than the red area, so when you think mouse should leave the red area, but it's actually not leave `.media-slider-wrap`, so `mouseleave` not trigger.

Comment: But if I change the parent container to match the size of the image I still have the exact problem. See updated snippet/codepen

Comment: Your .slider div is still full screen width, which makes the .media-slider-wrap full screen width

Comment: @GarrGodfrey My .slider is 500px? same with as .slider-image I thought

Answer (score 1):

you didn't set position for .media-slider-wrap

```
.media-slider-wrap {
  /* margin: 100px; */
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  /* make it work with firefox */
  width: -moz-fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code from codepen, which I think is inspired from [Why is the element not disappearing when mouse leaves area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201635/why-is-the-element-not-disappearing-when-mouse-leaves-area/69201787#69201787), It works now.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".media-slider-wrap").each(function () {
    const _this = $(this);
    _this.find('.slider-image').mousemove(function (e) {
      var offset = _this.offset();
      var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = (e.clientX - rect.left);
      var y = (e.clientY - rect.top);
      const sliderPaging = _this.find('.slider-paging');
      const moveX = x > rect.width - sliderPaging.width() ? rect.width - sliderPaging.width() : x;
      const moveY = y > rect.height - sliderPaging.height() ? rect.height - sliderPaging.height() : y;
      sliderPaging.show();
      sliderPaging
        .css("top", Math.max(moveY, rect.top))
        .css("left", Math.max(moveX, rect.left));
    });
    _this.find('.slider-image').mouseleave(function (e) {
      _this.find('.slider-paging').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.media-slider-wrap {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.slider-paging {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.slider-image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="media-slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider-image"></div>
  <div class="slider-paging">1/4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This look exactly the same answer as mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201635/why-is-the-element-not-disappearing-when-mouse-leaves-area/69201787#69201787

Comment: I just play around with this codepen in the question: https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/abwVXGY I think it's the version modified with your inspiration.

Comment: May be, but the code in your answer is exactly same as mine, no changes

Comment: No exactly, I change the event bind to `_this.find('.slider-image')`, and your code seems not working as expected, I think because the original codepen depend on your code, I never mean to copy your code, sorry for the confusing, I'll edit my answer to yours.

Comment: Can you point out why whats the bug in the answer that I provided?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your ".slider-paging" element is travellling with your cursor, which makes the `mouseleave` function fail to execute. You have to ensure that your ".slider-paging" element travells upto your red box boundary. Make the `top` and `left` of your `".slider-paging"` limit to the boundary of rectangle.

**Condition:** The left position should move from the left end of rectangle to the right end of rectangle. Similarly the top position should move from top end to the bottom end.

Here is the fix that I made.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".media-slider-wrap").each(function () {
    const _this = $(this);
    _this.mousemove(function (e) {
      var offset = _this.offset();
      var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = (e.clientX - rect.left);
      var y = (e.clientY - rect.top);
      const sliderPaging = $(this).find('.slider-paging');
      const moveX = x > rect.width - sliderPaging.width() ? rect.width - sliderPaging.width() : x;
      const moveY = y > rect.height - sliderPaging.height() ? rect.height - sliderPaging.height() : y;
      sliderPaging.show();
      sliderPaging
        .css("top", Math.max(moveY, rect.top))
        .css("left", Math.max(moveX, rect.left));
    });
    _this.mouseleave(function (e) {
      $(this).find('.slider-paging').hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.media-slider-wrap {
  width: fit-content;
}

.slider-paging {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.slider-image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="media-slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider-image"></div>
  <div class="slider-paging">1/4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works when moving the cursor left and right out of the red image, but I can move the cursor down out of the image and slider-paging is still showing

Comment: @monsaic123 the x-axis logic applies to the y-axis aswell. Restrict the `top` aswell with same logic and dependent dimensions, I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: @Niteesh This still doesn't hide the slider-paging when the cursor leaves from the left or top

Comment: @monsaic123 We have to check the left boundary aswell, ie, the left should be max of current cursor position and left end of rectangle, similarly with top

Comment: @monsaic123 I have updated the answer, please have a look into it